# How do you provide custom modifiers for your components?

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI makes a pervasive usage of the Builder pattern described [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/exploring-joshua-blochs-builder-design-pattern-in-java), providing a lot of custom modifiers to allow optional styling of your components. One of the reasons for using this pattern is that it allows you to write simple constructors (few parameters and less logic), and this is also why I personally like it a lot.

However, I couldn't find a way to provide a set of modifiers for my components, so here I am.

Say for instance that I'm trying to write my implementation of a slider and I want to provide an orientation change modifier to be invoked like this:

```
MySlider()
  .orientation(.vertical)
```

Now, I can create a `@State private var orientation: Orientation` but at this point I'm totally lost and don't know how to go on from this. What I tried:

```
func orientation(_ orientation: Orientation) {
    self.orientation = orientation
}
```

Which won't work because this expression doesn't return a view. Next attempt:

```
@ViewBuilder
func orientation(_ orientation: Orientation) -> some View {
    self.orientation = orientation
    self
}
```

Which won't work because expressions aren't allowed in a view. Namely `Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'`.

How do you work around this limitations to provide your own modifiers for your components?

Comment: It’s called a ViewModifier the documentation has a good example

Comment: @loremipsum: I know about ViewModifier but it's totally different from what I'm looking for. ViewModifier lets me define a single modifier that aggregates existing modifiers. Not to define my own modifiers for just one custom component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second strategy is close to one that can work. But, you don't return `some View` -- you return `Self`. Also, the mutated property should just be a plain property and not `@State`.

This works, for example:

```
struct MySlider: View {
    private var orientation: Orientation = .horizontal
    
    enum Orientation: String {
        case vertical, horizontal
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(orientation.rawValue)")
    }
}

extension MySlider {
    func orientation(_ orientation: Orientation) -> Self {
        var copy = self
        copy.orientation = orientation
        return copy
    }
}
```

There are other patterns to use as well such as a `ViewModifier`, which typically does not modify an internal property.

Yet another pattern could be using an `EnvironmentKey` that gets set by a function (or `ViewModifier`):

```
struct OrientationKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: MySlider.Orientation = .horizontal
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var orientation: MySlider.Orientation {
        get { self[OrientationKey.self] }
        set { self[OrientationKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct MySlider: View {
    @Environment(\.orientation) private var orientation: Orientation
    
    enum Orientation: String {
        case vertical, horizontal
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(orientation.rawValue)")
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func orientation(_ orientation: MySlider.Orientation) -> some View {
        self.environment(\.orientation, orientation)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I ended up opting for the first solution for its simplicity, but I really appreciated the insight on both the options

Comment: But does first option effect’s performance as creating instance again what if multiple properties which change at runtime. I want to know how this effects performance and view lifecycle.

Comment: @Srinivas Sounds like it could be a good opportunity for a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78029594/how-to-set-properties-of-custom-swiftui-view-using-builder-pattern